# Calculating for Load Resistance given a T network in between the source and the load

Tags: generator, basic, load

**Problem:** Calculate the value of load resistance (Rl) for which maximum transfer occurs.

[image]

**Attempt:** What I know is that for the maximum transfer to occur, the load resistance must be equal to the source resistance, in our case, the equivalent resistance of the resistors in T network.

Maximum transfer results to 50% efficiency, \$n = 0.5 = \frac{Rl}{Rl + Req.} \$. So If I could get the equivalent resistance of the T network, I can plug it in on the formula and get the load resistance. Problem is I don't know what to do next.

Any tip or help will be appreciated or a thorough / step by step explanation would be great for a newbie like me. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the Thevenin theorem?

Answer (score 1):

The hint you are looking for is "[Thevenin equivalence](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/thevenins-theorem/)", or "Thevenin's theorem".

Read about it, then try to find the Thevenin equivalent circuit for the elements \$V_T\$, \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$.

If you do that correctly, and then redraw the circuit, replacing those elements with their Thevenin equivalent, then you will find that the solution to your problem pretty much "pops out".

Answer (score 0):

A little help and not an answer: -

How would you calculate the effective source impedance of this: -

[image]

What steps would you go through when both resistors are equal (for instance)?

Looking back into the terminals, and imagining the battery produced 0 volts (still a valid value) what impedance would you see?

Comment: 4? Product sum of the 2 resistors? By going with that, I tried to solve the circuit. Product-sum of 20 and 60 then add it to 15 and got 30 ohms which is the answer according the answer key. I don't know if that is just a coincidence or that's really the solution.

Comment: Product/sum is the right answer when looking back into a source with a series and parallel resistor and, 30 is the correct answer too. Have you grasped this yet? Do you understand why we short out the source in order to examine its impedance?

Comment: Actually, I have very little foundation when it comes to circuit analysis but shorting out the source to examine the impedance and/or equivalent resistance is under thevenin's. Lastly, can I ask how can I get the maximum power of the load for the given problem? The answer is 2.7W, but I can't seem to get it. I used the formulas P = IV and P = \$ Vth^2 / 4Rth \$ but results to 4.8 V.

Comment: In my circuit, if the battery was (say) 24 volts but you didn't know that and you didn't know anything other than that the source impedance was 1 ohm (2||2) AND I gave you a multimeter what would you tell me was the source voltage?

Comment: I'm not sure. But there would be a voltage drop across the resistors, so it would be lower than the source voltage but maybe close to 24V.

Comment: Well, the two resistors form a 2:1 potential divider without any further loading so the equaivalent circuit is 12 volts in series with 1 ohm. Now think about your 24 volt supply and the 20 ohm and 60 ohm - how would that pan out in terms of an equivalent circuit? This is taking you to the final solution in case you were wondering!